# Custom Sisense Bar Chart using Blox Progress Bar not working

Tags: data-visualization, sisense

I want a Progress Bar that will display my current sales in comparison to the target. I found a similar tutorial and followed it exactly
This is the tutorial I followed :
https://profusion.com/insights/custom-bar-charts-in-sisense-blox-with-diego-cordero/

I have watched the youtube video for the same and used the exact code snippet from this blog. I am unable to get the progress bar configured correctly after trying several times. The purple tooltip is pointing before the progress bar even starts and seems static. Below is a screenshot for reference.
[image]

Please let me know what I am doing wrong and how to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue.
There is some inconsistency in formatting the percentage value.

Here's the workaround that fixed it for me:

Change **{panel:percentage}** reference to **{panel:percentage}%** in the script and in the "percentage" field in the panel, multiply the value by 100 (so that instead of 0.21, You will have 21, for example)

Then it should display the values correctly :)